# drop textbox on table using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have created a `table` which is draggable and droppable using jQuery and I have also created textbox, which is draggable. When my textbox is dropped on a `table cell`, I want the cell to adjust its size according to the size of the textbox. Is this possible? Please help?

This is the code I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input').draggable({
          cancel: null
        });
        $('tr>td').droppable({
          drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).html('droped');
          }
        });
        $('table').draggable({
          cancel: null
        });
      });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="draggable"></input>
    <table id="droppable" border="1" style="height: 100px;width: 200px">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/dqg2r6xx/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').draggable({
    cancel: null
  });
  $('#droppable td').droppable({
    accept: "input",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).html('droped');
    }
  });
  $('table').draggable({
    cancel: null
  });
});
```

Problem here is that it does not attach to the table. So if you move it around, the `input` is still in position.

In regards to the sizing, it's adjusting the cell but not the table size. The `input` is wider than `100px` so it stretches the cell to it's max and can do no more.